# Scope validation is failing for pub/sub and calendars

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I have developed an enterprise application which uses gmail sync for users. Have also implemented webhooks via pub/sub. Currently, we are into production. But our pub/sub scopes are not approved by google.

Scopes that used for pub/sub:

1. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub

Have few other scopes issue as well:

1. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events
2. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly the question is?

Comment: I have submitted my app for google verification. Google is currently not verifying these above scopes.